# Error installing phone gap on MAC

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to install phonegap on MAC, using

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/npm install -g phonegap
```

but am getting the below error. I have installed node.js.

> npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
>   npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
>   npm ERR! node v0.12.7
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
>   npm ERR! file sh
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno ENOENT
>   npm ERR! syscall spawn
>
> npm ERR! cordova@2.7.4 install: `node bootstrap.js`
>   npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the cordova@2.7.4 install script 'node bootstrap.js'.
>   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the cordova package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     node bootstrap.js
>   npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls cordova
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/janhavibagwe/npm-debug.log

Comment: Is there anything in `/Users/janhavibagwe/npm-debug.log` related to this?

Comment: The error section has the same comments.
11977 error code ELIFECYCLE
11978 error errno ENOENT
11979 error syscall spawn
11980 error cordova@2.7.4 install: `node bootstrap.js`
11980 error spawn ENOENT
11981 error Failed at the cordova@2.7.4 install script 'node bootstrap.js'.
11981 error This is most likely a problem with the cordova package,
11981 error not with npm itself.
11981 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
11981 error     node bootstrap.js
11981 error You can get their info via:
11981 error     npm owner ls Cordova

Answer (score 0):

What version of node are you running?

```
node -v
```

The current version is v0.12.7, If you have an old version try and update it.

[Just saw your version in your error so ignore that]

Also try

```
npm cache clean
```

then try installing phonegap again but without the path so just

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How did you install node? via brew? Have you also added npm to you PATH? You can check your path from the terminal echo $PATH.

Comment: used   sudo npm install -g cordova instead of the keyword phonegap and it worked. Thanks for the headstart Mark!